# How do I create a circle border of 86% of any other number rather than 100% in Adobe xd?

Tags: shapes, adobe-xd, outline

I am trying to create a pie chart in which I am having two separate values.

1. The bigger number
2. The smaller number

I am representing the bigger number as an outer circle radius, but the problem is I want to create the exact amount of it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want accuracy, try this method instead.

1. Calculate the required angle, which will be 14%*360°=50.4°
2. Using the pen tool, draw a horizontal line from the centre of the circle

[image]

3. Rotate it -50.4°, and reposition at the centre of the circle

[image]

[image]

4. Using the pen tool draw a horizontal line from the centre anchor

[image]

5. Set the fill to white, and border none.

[image]

6. Here's the result

[image]

Comment: it worked. Thank you so much.